# Sub groups under groups

Tags: 8, group

Anybody has idea about how we can have Sub Groups under Drupal Group?

This module; https://www.drupal.org/project/group, will manage grouping of content, users.... perfectly.

But we are looking to have a hierarchical Group functionality (Group inside a group).

Use Case:
An Organization has various Groups and Departments.

Main Company -> Organizations(Groups) -> Departments (subgroups)
Departments/Groups Should be able to administer content/users.

Answer (score 0):

[Subgroup module](https://www.drupal.org/project/subgroup) should suit your needs. Make sure to read [this short documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2710757) as well